# ViewPager2 without using Viewpager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I want to create my own version of ViewPager2 so that I can control the animation design and orientation capabilities. Basically, I'm trying to have a scrolling up and down load new users while left and right would be more information about that user.

I tried using custom animations with swipe gestures, which works exactly as I wanted, except I don't get the control of dynamically animating the swiping direction. Essentially, it still works like a button animation - you might swipe in the direction you want but the animation speed/feel/etc is always the same animation vs. ViewPager2's ability to move with the gesture.

I experimented with OnDragListeners which do give me the "Tinder card movement" animation effect but I don't want to allow for animations in all directions. I was able to use a ViewPager2 for the horizontal direction while using the OnDragListener to override the swiping (using OnLongClick). When you drag up or down it has the same issue of the transition animation being the same speed/feel/etc everytime instead of the nice ViewPager2 slide on touch effect.

I only need 4 fragments for each user so my next idea was to try a horizontalscrollview in a recyclerview but that's working either.

Any suggestions for an approach I might not have considered?